# How can I make my files upload faster to sites like Facebook and YouTube?

Tags: facebook, youtube, video, images, upload

How can I speed up my uploads of videos and photos to websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can do is clear your cookies and history, which reduces the amount of data that gets sent to the server in some cases.

Second, somewhat obvious, is to make sure you're network connection is only doing one thing. Stop browsing and see if anybody else is on the same network connection as you.

Third option is to try to reduce the size of the file, which is a much broader topic. Sometimes this is impossible as files like .jpg and .gif are already compressed. You can reduce the quality of the image [in some way](http://www.ehow.com/how_6236_optimize-picture-web.html), but this usually isn't worth the time unless you are using the photos on a professional website. The situation is pretty much the same for videos. If you are uploading the files to a site like rapidshare.com, you can compress them first, usually using the [zip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29). :D

Comment: Its pointless compressing photos and videos, given that most popular image/video formats are _already_ compressed.